# Configuring IIS Express failed with the following error: Unable to acces the IIS metabase

Tags: asp.net, iis, visual-studio-2013, iis-express

When I try to create a new ASP.NET Empty Web Site in Visual Studio Premium 2013 on my windows 8.1 machine, I get the following error message:

Configuring IIS Express failed with the following error:
Unable to acces the IIS metabase. You do not have sufficient privilege to acces IIS web sites on your machine.

I am aware questions about this error have been asked all around the web numerous times and I have tried every solution I came upon so far, but nothing has worked. I have reinstalled Visual Studio, I have reinstalled IIS several times (and included all options), I have obviously run Visual Studio as administrator and I have navigated to C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\Export and clicked "Continue" on the popups I got (for permission to access the folders).
I am completely out of ideas and sincerely hope that one of you can help me with my problems, thanks.

Comment: IIS Express is not IIS. Try to uninstall IIS 7 or 8 Express from Programs and then reinstall it by finding its installer from Microsoft downloads.

Comment: I know it's IIS Express, I just called it IIS because it was shorter and I thought it would be clear enough what I meant. I have reinstalled it like you said though, at least twice.

Comment: Can you back up and then delete the IIS Express folder in your My Document folder? Then by creating a new web application in Visual Studio to use IIS Express those files will be recreated. Don't use IIS for short for IIS Express. They are completely different things and you just lead to confusion.

Comment: There wasn't a IIS Express folder in documents, which I found strange so I  tried making a web project in Visual Studio once again and it miraculously worked! No idea why it works now though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, somehow it started working, I think it might have to do with me repairing Visual Studio via the programs and features dialogue, which I did because my SASS wasn't compiling, but apparently it fixed the IIS Express problems too. Quite strange, considering I did a complete reinstall of Visual Studio only yesterday...

Comment: For some reason your IIS Express installation was corrupt. Reinstalling VS or other bits won't help much when the root cause is that default IIS Express folder in My Documents was missing. That folder must be recreated as I commented above.

Comment: Yes, but I didn't do it that way, I never deleted it manually, I guess it was deleted when I repaired VS.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you have to go to Programs and Features->Windows Components and expand Internet Information Server and add the Metabase compatibility feature. I doubt that VS installer will do that as the Metabase is depricated since IIS 7 which replaced it with the applicationHost.config (XML) file.

Comment: Well, I already did that, it's what I meant by include options, I checked every single feature under Internet Information Services in the Windows Features dialog. But what's this applicationHost.config file? Maybe it has something to do with that?

Comment: Could be... I think that in IIS 7, Metabase compatibility is a COM layer over applicationHost. And now I think about it, applicationHost.config is a protected file so maybe you just need to run as admin.